# Slack include SIP URL in the message

Tags: hyperlink, sip, slack

I'm adding messages that includes url markdown to a slack channel using this format:

```
<http://somesite.com|friendly name> -> works
<mailto:email@domain.com|friendly name2> -> works
<sip:email@domain.com|friendly name2> -> url markdown doesn't works
```

When I use `<sip://email@domain.com|friendly name2>` the markdown convert it to link but the sip client fails to connect due to the extra "//"

Any idea how to make sip links on slack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Slack's documentation](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting#linking_to_urls) only mentions `http`/`https` and `mailto` schemes for automatic linking, but I played around with their [message builder](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder) and noticed the following:

- Schemes followed by `://` seem to be generally supported
- In addition there seems to be a whitelist of other schemes supported. The only ones I found working so far are `mailto` and `skype`.

While that matches your observation it looks like there is no way to have automatic linking for the `sip` scheme.

What you could do is to write a Slack App, which provides a command (e.g. `/sip email@domain.com`), which will print a link to a website which redirects you to the proper `sip`-URL. I believe that's the approach other services like [Zoom](https://zoom.us/) use as well for their Slack integration.

An interesting alternative could be to contact Slack and kindly ask them to add `sip`-URLs to their whitelist.

Comment: Just sent a request on Slack's contact us form